# How to troubleshoot the following js index script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an automatic index script, that creates a list of headers 1-6, an tries to grab the contents of the headers(`<h2>`...content... `</h2>`), creates an id tag for the headers, and throws the content of it in the id tag.

But it has a bug. It grabs the content of the last header and throws that in the id tag of all headers.

I don't know how to properly phrase this, or to fix this bug. I have been at it for a while. I should be taking a break. But, i can't seem to let this go... Help...

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blade1989/90wpksvk/3/)

**code**:

```
function index() {
    var index =
        "<ul id=\"EuroTOC\" style=\"display: block;\">" +
        "<li id=\"tocid\">Table of Content <button id=\"closetoc\" onclick=\"closetoc()\">[-]</button>";

    var newLine, el, title, link, hid;

    // searches every tag you put in here
    $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").each(function() {

        el = $(this);
        title = el.text();
        link = "#" + el.attr("id");
        id = "#" + el.text().replace(/\s/g, "");
        hid = el.text().replace(/\s/g, "");


// -----\/ Not Working properly \/----- 

//  Takes the last header id="last"
// applys that on all headers : h1-6

    var select = $('h1');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h2');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h3');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h4');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h5');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h6');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    // var select = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
    // select.attr('id', ""+ title +"");

// ------^ Not Working properly ^-------

    // Works Fine:

        newLine =
            "<li>\n" +
                "<a href='" + id + "' title='" + title + "' >" + title +
            "</a>\n" +
            "</li>\n";

        index += newLine;

    });


    index +=
        "</li>" +
        "</ul>";

    $("article").prepend(index);
}
```

Output:

```
<article>

<ul style="display: block;" id="EuroTOC"><li id="tocid">Table of Content <button onclick="closetoc()" id="closetoc">[-]</button></li><li>
<a title="Dynamic Table Of Content" href="#DynamicTableOfContent">Dynamic Table Of Content</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Jquery script" href="#Jqueryscript">Jquery script</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="How do many licks does a giraffe?" href="#Howdomanylicksdoesagiraffe?">How do many licks does a giraffe?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Which Frank is?" href="#WhichFrankis?">Which Frank is?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Is fourteen enough?" href="#Isfourteenenough?">Is fourteen enough?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Is a circle an oval y/n?" href="#Isacircleanovaly/n?">Is a circle an oval y/n?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Many mongerals manifest mountains" href="#Manymongeralsmanifestmountains">Many mongerals manifest mountains</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="How would you like a soda drink?" href="#Howwouldyoulikeasodadrink?">How would you like a soda drink?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="I would very much like a soda drink." href="#Iwouldverymuchlikeasodadrink.">I would very much like a soda drink.</a>
</li>
<li>
<a title="Please Header Script work" href="#PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Please Header Script work</a>
</li>
</ul>
      <h1 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Dynamic Table Of Content</h1>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>  


      <h2 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Jquery script</h2>

        <p> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">How do many licks does a giraffe?</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h4 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Which Frank is?</h4>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h5 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Is fourteen enough?</h5>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h6 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Is a circle an oval y/n?</h6>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Many mongerals manifest mountains</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">How would you like a soda drink?</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">I would very much like a soda drink.</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3 id="PleaseHeaderScriptwork">Please Header Script work</h3>

        <p>   
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

    </article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every single header, you're setting the `hid` value into the `id` attribute of every header. You do this for all the headers, and each overwrites the previous one, with the last one being the only one remaining at the end.

The solution is to replace all the "not working" code with this:

```
el.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");
```

No need to search for that header element, you already have it.

Comment: Plus one for the helpful explanation! and accepted answer, because it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's doing just what you asked it to. Every time through the loop, you're creating an id, then applying it to *every* `h1`, `h2`, etc. in the document. So whatever id was set *last* remains on all of them.

What you *want* to do is set the `id` of the element you're examining right now. You already have a reference to that element, in `el`, so just:

```
el.attr('id', hid);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing

```
var select = $('h1');
select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");
```

you assign the id attribute to all h1 tags, where as you you need to be setting the attribute on the current element

```
el.attr('id', hid);
```

**Update:**

I had a go at re-implementing the code here in case its any use for reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/2wadx9t5/

Answer (score 0):

Please update the script index function as below remove the commented code if you need

```
function index() {
    var index =
        "<ul id=\"EuroTOC\" style=\"display: block;\">" +
        "<li id=\"tocid\">Table of Content <button id=\"closetoc\" onclick=\"closetoc()\">[-]</button>";

    var newLine, el, title, link, hid;

    // searches every tag you put in here
    $("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").each(function() {

        el = $(this);
        title = el.text();
        id = el.text().replace(/\s/g, "");      
        el.attr('id', ""+ id +"");
        id = '#' + id;
        link = "#" + el.attr("id");
        hid = el.text().replace(/\s/g, "");

// -----\/ Not Working properly \/----- 

//  Takes the last header id="last"
// applys that on all headers : h1-6

    /*var select = $('h1');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h2');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h3');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h4');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h5');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");

    var select = $('h6');
    select.attr('id', ""+ hid + "");*/

    /*var select = $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
    select.attr('id', ""+ id +"");*/

// ------^ Not Working properly ^-------

    // Works Fine:

        newLine =
            "<li>\n" +
                "<a href='" + id + "' title='" + title + "' >" + title +
            "</a>\n" +
            "</li>\n";

        index += newLine;

    });


    index +=
        "</li>" +
        "</ul>";

    $("article").prepend(index);




$('#toc').attr('style', 'display: none;');


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90wpksvk/5/) for an example.

I used `:header` selector to walk all of the headers in line. The way you had it, it would walk all `h1` first then the `h2` and so on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(document).on('click', '#toc', function(event){
        $('#EuroTOC').toggle();
    });

    // searches every tag you put in here
    $("article :header").each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'toc'+index);
        var li = $('<li></li>');
        var a = $('<a></a>');
        a.html($(this).html());
        a.attr('href', '#toc'+index);
        li.html(a);
        $('#EuroTOC').append(li);
    });    
});
```

I also changed the HTML

```
<button id="toc" title="Table Of Contents">[+]</button>
<ul id="EuroTOC"></ul>
    <article>
      <h1>Dynamic Table Of Content</h1>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>  


      <h2>Jquery script</h2>

        <p> 
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3>How do many licks does a giraffe?</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h4>Which Frank is?</h4>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h5>Is fourteen enough?</h5>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h6>Is a circle an oval y/n?</h6>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3>Many mongerals manifest mountains</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3>How would you like a soda drink?</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3>I would very much like a soda drink.</h3>

        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

      <h3>Please Header Script work</h3>

        <p>   
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>

    </article>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#EuroTOC {
    display:none;
}
```